# getting the current date in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Im trying to get the current date inside my rails model like this:

Inside Photo.rb

```
  Paperclip.interpolates :prefix  do |attachment, style|
      :today_date => Date.today.to_s
      "#{:today_date}/#{attachment.instance.image_file_name}"
  end
```

When I send a Photo to the server from the client I get an error and the following console output on the server. This tells me that there is a problem with the "Date" function

Server Console:

```
 Started POST "/photos.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-20 13:47:35 -0800
 13:47:35 web.1  | 
 13:47:35 web.1  | SyntaxError 
             (/Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/test/app/models/photo.rb:22: syntax 
               error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
 13:47:35 web.1  |      :today_date => Date.today.to_s
 13:47:35 web.1  |                    ^):
 13:47:35 web.1  |   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the current date into this variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :prefix  do |attachment, style|
  "#{Date.today.to_s}/#{attachment.instance.image_file_name}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to assign a variable, you're using a hash syntax. It should look like this:

```
  Paperclip.interpolates :prefix  do |attachment, style|
      today_date = Date.today.to_s
      "#{today_date}/#{attachment.instance.image_file_name}"
  end
```

Comment: I tried that. In fact thats the first thing I tried. But it didn't work so I switched to the above written version

Comment: Just get rid of the colon.
`"#{today_date}/#{attachment.instance.image_file_name}"`

Comment: Nowadays rubocop suggests `Time.zone.today`